# which file is responsible for view a custom modules's functionalities in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am new to drupal and eagerly wanna know more about it.I am creating a custom module which will show the employee type entities. Can anybody tell me to find out the view file of a custom module .

Comment: What do you mean by view file?

Comment: You are right @D34dman,as per my concern i feel View file means the page drupal will render as the overlay which is responsible for the view of a page or a dialog box that appears almost every settings that we are doing on it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page Drupal will use to render your entity

**[Handbook page one Drupal.org about Theming Custom Entities](http://drupal.org/node/1238606)**

> There are three pieces, or more specifically functions, that are
>   required to theme the output of a custom entity: hook_menu(), Page
>   Callback, and the MODULE_theme() Hook.

**[View Mode Templates : Module](http://drupal.org/project/view_mode_templates)**

> Lets you create entity view mode templates as
>   `ENTITY-TYPE--BUNDLE--VIEW-MODE.tpl.php`. Templates can be used in
>   custom themes and modules.

Also comment section in [this](http://technify.me/cms/drupal/theming-custom-entities-in-drupal-7/) post talks about some special cases.